# How to draw fibonacci retracement in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was able to draw only technical indicators like Linear,SMA,EMA,MACD in highcharts. But is there any js like `technical-indicators.src.js` is avilable in highcharts to draw fibonacci retracement in highcharts?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment it is not avaiable, so you need to prepare or your own. I advice to request your suggestion on our website highcharts.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to use annotations for fibonacci retracement[Fibonacci Retracement example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/samples/stock/annotations/fibonacci-retracements)

```
annotations: [
        fibonacciRetracements(Date.UTC(2016, 10, 14), 105, Date.UTC(2017, 8, 4), 170)
    ]
```